# Should we rename the host name part of the email files when migrating to another email server?

Tags: email, email-server, migration, exim, qmail

The original email file name pattern looks like this:

```
1447902202.31829.old-domain.com,S=15459960_2,S
```

If we are going to migrate to another email server, should we rename the host name part of the file name so that it becomes:

```
1447902202.31829.new-domain.com,S=15459960_2,S
```

Or it simply does not matter? Some users might have been using different email clients to access their emails via IMAP. Do typical email clients use the email file name as the id to identify an email or they will actually inspect inside the email file and locate the message id from the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you haven't do that. IMAP server do not depend on filenames except the suffixes that encodes length and status of your messages. The only thing you have to do is to reindex your maildirs. That could be achieved by removing of existent index files so qmail will reindex maildir on the next access via IMAP.